# Cypress Intercept, refining url

Tags: javascript, url, cypress, cypress-intercept

I'm intercepting a request with Cypress and I'm trying not to hardcode something. To make it work correctly, I have to add a "1" since I'm trying to intercept something like this:

```js
/api/v1/contacts/cfs:12345/forms/144543
```

The problem is that there are other requests like `/forms/something` that are being intercepted if I use forms/**, leading to this:

```js
let urlResponse = '/api/v1/contacts/cfs:' + $code + '/forms/1**'
```

Is there any regex or something that could let me just intercept the URL that's `forms/number` and not `forms/something` or `forms/number/something`?

Answer (score 1):

Here is some regex for matching just the .../forms/number pattern.

```js
const inputs = [
  '/api/v1/contacts/cfs:12345/forms/144543',
  '/api/v1/contacts/cfs:12345/forms/something',
  '/api/v1/contacts/cfs:12345/forms/144543/something'
];

const regex = new RegExp('/api/v1/contacts/cfs:12345/forms/[0-9]+$');

for (let input of inputs) {
  const isMatch = regex.test(input);
  console.log(isMatch);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Cypress uses minimatch to validate a url, so you can use:

```
const part = '12345';
cy.intercept(`/api/v1/contacts/cfs:${part}/forms/1[0-9]*`).as('alias');
```

And check if it is actually matching what is expected in this way:

```
expect(Cypress.minimatch('/api/v1/contacts/cfs:12345/forms/144543', `/api/v1/contacts/cfs:${part}/forms/1[0-9]*`)).to.be.true;
expect(Cypress.minimatch('/api/v1/contacts/cfs:12345/forms/something', `/api/v1/contacts/cfs:${part}/forms/1[0-9]*`)).to.be.false;
expect(Cypress.minimatch('/api/v1/contacts/cfs:12345/forms/144543/something', `/api/v1/contacts/cfs:${part}/forms/1[0-9]*`)).to.be.false;
```